# Spline Animation disappears when deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, spline

I made a 3D design using Spline and I added to my application, when I run the application locally using
**npm run build**  it works perfectly I can see the design and everything. However, when I try to deploy the application on the internet the Spline design will disappear I don't understand why this is happening, I have deployed the application to Vercel, Firebase, and Heroku. My application is a React app with Node.js.

```
 <div className="relative" id="home">
        <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/0TUuMfCgXS3Xkkuo/scene.splinecode" />
          <div className="absolute bottom-10 w-full flex justify-center items-center">
            <div className="shadow-md p-4 flex items-center justify-center bg-zinc-900 rounded-3xl ">
              <p className="text-white">Press and drag to orbit</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with iFrames without server-side rendering. You have to wrap it inside a component. You can import that component with dynamic from 'next/dynamic':

```
const IFrameComponent = dynamic(() => import('path/to/component'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```